# Type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, bloc, dio

How to fetch data from the model that look like this http://lovemonster.my.id/hospital to my BLoC builder in form of list? i got an error message when i fetch it `Type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'` and this is my provider:

```
class ApiProvider {
  final Dio _dio = Dio();
  final String _url = 'http://lovemonster.my.id/hospital';

  Future<HospitalListModel> fetchHospitalList() async {
    try {
      Response response = await _dio.get(_url);
      return HospitalListModel.fromJson(response.data);
    } catch (error, stacktrace) {
      print("Exception occurred: $error stackTrace: $stacktrace");
      return Future.error("");
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my repository:

```
class ApiRepository {
  final _provider = ApiProvider();

  Future<HospitalListModel> fetchHospitalList() {
    return _provider.fetchHospitalList();
  }
}
class NetworkError extends Error {}
```

this is the model, in case you want to know how it looks like:

```
class HospitalListModel {
  int? id;
  String? title;
  String? content;
  String? image;
  String? phone;
  String? coordinates;
  String? website;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;

  HospitalListModel({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.content,
    this.image,
    this.phone,
    this.coordinates,
    this.website,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
  });

  HospitalListModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'] as int?;
    title = json['title'] as String?;
    content = json['content'] as String?;
    image = json['image'] as String?;
    phone = json['phone'] as String?;
    coordinates = json['coordinates'] as String?;
    website = json['website'] as String?;
    createdAt = json['created_at'] as String?;
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'] as String?;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> json = <String, dynamic>{};
    json['id'] = id;
    json['title'] = title;
    json['content'] = content;
    json['image'] = image;
    json['phone'] = phone;
    json['coordinates'] = coordinates;
    json['website'] = website;
    json['created_at'] = createdAt;
    json['updated_at'] = updatedAt;
    return json;
  }
}
```

can anyone show me how to fetch the data from my API

Comment: You are trying to assign a list to a singluar model object not an array of said model object i.e. array to a variable whose type is a single key-value pair,

Comment: can you please post HospitalListModel?

Comment: im already add the model

Answer (score 1):

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final hospitalListModel = hospitalListModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

List<HospitalListModel> hospitalListModelFromJson(String str) => List<HospitalListModel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => HospitalListModel.fromJson(x)));

String hospitalListModelToJson(List<HospitalListModel> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class HospitalListModel {
    HospitalListModel({
        this.id,
        this.title,
        this.content,
        this.image,
        this.phone,
        this.coordinates,
        this.website,
        this.createdAt,
        this.updatedAt,
    });

    dynamic id;
    dynamic title;
    dynamic content;
    dynamic image;
    dynamic phone;
    dynamic coordinates;
    dynamic website;
    dynamic createdAt;
    dynamic updatedAt;

    factory HospitalListModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => HospitalListModel(
        id: json["id"],
        title: json["title"],
        content: json["content"],
        image: json["image"],
        phone: json["phone"],
        coordinates: json["coordinates"],
        website: json["website"],
        createdAt: json["created_at"],
        updatedAt: json["updated_at"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "title": title,
        "content": content,
        "image": image,
        "phone": phone,
        "coordinates": coordinates,
        "website": website,
        "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
        "updated_at": updatedAt.toIso8601String(),
    };
}
```

---

call this from here

```
final hospitalListModel = hospitalListModelFromJson(jsonString);
```

Example:

```
  Future<List<HospitalListModel>> fetchHospitalList() async {
    try {
      Response response = await _dio.get(_url);
      return hospitalListModelFromJson(response.body);
    } catch (error, stacktrace) {
      print("Exception occurred: $error stackTrace: $stacktrace");
      return Future.error("");
    }
  }
```

Comment: hello, it showing an error: A value of type 'List<HospitalListModel>' can't be returned from the method 'fetchHospitalList' because it has a return type of 'Future<HospitalListModel>'.

Comment: Future<List<HospitalListModel>> Change here /now check i have edited